# How to clear entry in Django session

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-sessions

I have a search form that I use to then list the objects with a paginated ListView. For the pagination to work, I need to keep the form fields in the list view, which I did so far using session. In the view of the form, I want to clear the values of the potential previous searches. So I have something like this:

```
    class SearchForm( forms.Form ):
      name = forms.CharField()

    def SearchView( request ):
        form = SearchForm() 
        <CLEAR SESSION ENTRY HERE>
        return render( request, 'search.html', {
            'form': form,
        } )



    class listView( ListView ):
      model = myModel
      template_name = "list.html"
      paginate_by = 10
      form = None


      def get( self, request, *args, **kwargs ):
          form = SearchForm( request.GET )  # A form bound to the POST data

        if form.is_valid():

          name = form.cleaned_data['name']
          if name:
            self.request.session.setdefault( 'search_form', {} )['name'] = name

        return super( orderList_view, self ).get( request, *args, **kwargs )

      def get_queryset( self ):
        searchFilters = self.request.session.get( 'search_form', {} )
        queryset = myModel.objects.all()
        if 'name' in  searchFilters:
          queryset = queryset.filter( mymodel__name__iexact = searchFilters.get( 'name' ) )
        return queryset
```

My problem is clearing the entry.
If I do it that way

```
    request.session.pop( 'search_form', None )
```

everything works perfectly.

However if I do it that way

```
    request.session['search_form'] = dict()
```

the session seems to be cleared when I go on the next page. The 1st page contains only entries that match my search, and the total number of page is correct. But when I click "next", it then returns all the entries, the searchFilters is empty.

I don't understand why, since  doing session.setdefault( 'search_form', {}) should make the two clearing methods the same.Can someone explain me why one works and not the other, and why is my session "cleared" in the second case?

Btw, I use a dictionary search_form inside the session because in reality I have several search fields, and it's "cleaner" to keep them together

Comment: What is the question you are asking?

Comment: Sorry, not clear enough :). Why one works and not the other, and why is my session "cleared"?